# Detect global click UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a visible grid that has to collapse when I click outside of it. I solved it for half.

MainPage.xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Button One" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnShowGrid" Content="Show Grid" Click="btnShowGrid_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <Grid x:Name="ControlGrid" PointerEntered="ControlGrid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="ControlGrid_PointerExited" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Background="LightGreen" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Margin="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
    bool PointerInGrid = false;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPointerPressed(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPointerPressed(e);
        if (!PointerInGrid)
        {
            ControlGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    private void btnShowGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    private void ControlGrid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerInGrid = true;
    }
    private void ControlGrid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerInGrid = false;
    }
```

If I click into the Grid this remains visible, if I click out the grid goes to collapsed, so far everything is fine but, if I click the btnOne the grid remains visible.

So is possible detect a global click to collapse the grid?

As always thanks in advance.

Code that works in windows form:

```
    const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210;
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY)
            {
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PointerPressed` event is swallowed by the button so it cannot reach the underlying parent, where the event handler `OnPointerPressed` is executed.

There is a technique to pass the event down to the parent, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585392).

You can do it like this, in the page's constructor

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //...other code

    //then add this line
    this.btnOne.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerPressedEvent,
      new PointerEventHandler((s, e) => { e.Handled = false; }), true);
}
```

A second thought: Maybe you can just handle btnOne’s PointerPressed event, and in the handler set its event argument’s Handled property as false. Don’t need to use **AddHandler**, I mean. Give it a try.

Comment: For btnOne is right. But I wanted to intercept any click. I update the question with a code stack that works in windows form to better understand what i would like to achieve.

Comment: The mechanism, that the event is fired in parent then passed to the child if not handled by the parent, is called _event tunneling_, like the PreviewMouseDown event in WPF, is always fired in the parent first. But in UWP, seems tunneling is not supported, only bubbling events are supported, that is, events are first handled by the child. I think the WinForm sample code you provided is the Win32 equivalent of tunneling.

Comment: So, for UWP there is a way to close a UserControl if you click outside of it?

Comment: @LightGreen consider using a [flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs), which behaviors exactly the way you want. Read the remarks for its use scenarios.

Comment: The last thing but, with the flyout I can change the closing animation then when I click outside of it?

Comment: @LightGreen You can control the basic animations like fade in/fade out effect by setting transitioncollection of the user control. Google with these keywords “uwp flyout transition” to get started.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I known, the UWP is sandboxed, we can't use `WndProc` method to receive Window event Messages.

> Specific Windows Runtime controls may have class-based handling for the PointerPressed input event. If so, the control probably has an override for the method OnPointerPressed. Typically the event is marked handled by the class handler, and the PointerPressed event is not raised for handling by any user code handlers on that control. For example, ButtonBase has class handling that handles PointerPressed and instead fires Click.

For more info, please refer [PointerPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerPressed).

When we click the `Button`, the `OnPointerPressed` event will not be fired.

If you want to your `Button` can fire `OnPointerPressed` event, you can create a class that inherited the `Button` class. In the class, you can override the `OnPointerPresse` event.

For example:

```
class MyButton: Button
{
    protected override void OnPointerPressed(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

By the way, if we override OnPointerPressed event in class that inherited the `Button` class, the `Click` event will not be fired.